# HAProxy: Backend with subdirectory / subpath / subfolder?

Tags: backend, subdirectory, haproxy

I am trying to achieve this:

```
http://front-end       --> http://back-end/app-1
http://front-end/app-2 --> http://back-end/app-2-another-path
```

So that requests will be handled this way:

```
http://front-end/do-this       --> http://back-end/app-1/do-this
http://front-end/app-2/do-that --> http://back-end/app-2-another-path/do-that
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can achieve this `"http://front-end/app-2/do-that --> http://back-end/app-2-another-path/do-that"` with the following configuration:

```
frontend http   
   #match url ending with /xxxxx/do-that
   acl do-that path_end -i /app-2/do-that

   use_backend server1 if do-that

backend server1
   reqirep ^([^\ :]*)\ /app-2/(.*)     \1\ /app-2-another-path/\2
   server server 168.192.X.X
```

[Here](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-reqirep) is more information on **reqirep**.

Comment: if using this on more recent haproxy (version 2.2.9) the log states:
The 'reqirep' directive is not supported anymore since HAProxy 2.1. Use 'http-request replace-header' instead.
but I did it this way (each one in its own line, seems in comments code can't be in multiple lines):

    `acl my_subfolder path_beg -i /app-2-another-path/`

    `http-request set-path /app-2-another-path/%[path] if !my_subfolder`

Comment: if you are using an even more recent haproxy version, use `http-request replace-path` as described [here](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/path-based-routing-with-haproxy)